# ReferenceError ao exportar uma variável

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

no arquivo principal "App.js", exporto a const "gameSets" para o arquivo no caminho "data/tokenGenerator.js". Mas, ao rodar a aplicação acontece esse seguinte erro:

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'gameSets' before initialization
    at Object.enemyDificult (file:///C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/js-rpg/data/tokenGenerator.js:52:17)
    at Object.enemyGenerator (file:///C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/js-rpg/data/tokenGenerator.js:75:27)
    at file:///C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/js-rpg/data/tokenGenerator.js:80:24
```

o App.js:

```
import {  enemiesSet, jogador, TokenGenerator } from "./data/tokenGenerator.js";

const gameSets = {
    velocidade: () =>  {return Math.round(Math.random() * 10)},
}

export { gameSets }
```

O tokenGenerator (caminho: ./data/tokenGenerator.js):

```
import { gameSets } from '../App.js'

class TokenGenerator {
    constructor(nome, hp, armadura, velocidade, nivel) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.hp = hp
        this.armadura = armadura;
        this.velocidade = velocidade;
        this.nivel = nivel;
    }
}



const jogador = new TokenGenerator('Thiago', 15, 3, Math.round(Math.random() * 10), 1)

const enemiesSet = {
    // cria um objeto com as informações do inimigo
    enemyDificult(dificult) {
        if(dificult == 'easy') {
            return new TokenGenerator(
                undefined, 
                jogador.hp - 5, 
                jogador.armadura - 3, 
                gameSets.velocidade, 
                null)
        }
}
```

O que pode estar acontecendo para que o gameSets não esteja sendo acessado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você está fazendo uma importação circular no seu código. Em App.js:

```
import {  enemiesSet, jogador, TokenGenerator } from "./data/tokenGenerator.js";
```

Você está importando o módulo `"./data/tokenGenerator.js"`. Porém, nesse módulo você está importando `App.js`:

```
import { gameSets } from '../App.js'
```

Só que para `App.js` exportar `gameSets` ele precisa concluir a importação de `"./data/tokenGenerator.js"` que por sua vez precisa que `App.js`. Logo, nenhum dos dois módulos vai conseguir completar seu código para que você use o resultado.

Concluindo, seu código possui importação circular. Um módulo fica esperando pelo outro para que possa exportar seu resultado. Veja imagem:
[image: imagem da importação circular]

Porém, veja que em `App.js` você não precisa importar `"./data/tokenGenerator.js"`. Você não faz uso de nenhuma função ou variável de lá. Logo, se você atualizar `App.js` para:

```
const gameSets = {
    velocidade: () =>  {return Math.round(Math.random() * 10)},
}

export { gameSets }
```

Seu código deve funcionar.